# multiple soa/api gateways to satisfy internal and external customers

Tags: api, soa

I have come across API and Service architectures where API/Svc gateway is positioned in DMZ for authorization/authentication of external(not employees) consumers. But, in my case, we have internal consumers also. The internal consumers are behind an intranet firewall that isolates them from DMZ. My question is do i need to deploy a separate instance of API/Svc gateway for internal users for authentication/authorization that is within intranet or should internal api access have to go through the intranet firewall to DMZ and back into the intranet?

Comment: I have a similar problem. Have you managed to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the gateway architecture. For example [Tyk.io](https://tyk.io) separates UI/Portal from the gateway nodes. If the UI components and the gateway nodes are separate then you can have a single portal but differentiated gateways to handle traffic from different sources.